# Микротик не дает интернет другим роутерам

Tags: сеть

Поставил микротик дома, он подключен по кабелю провайдера в 1й порт.
Дальше идет витая пара на свитч, от микротика. От свитча витая пара идет в другое помещение, там стоит роутер. Интернет на микротике есть, там настройки по умолчанию, то есть я могу подключить как по кабелю, так и по вай фай сети, будет работать. А вот если я подключаюсь к роутеру, который стоит в другом помещении, интернета нет.
Что можно сделать? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Обратитесь к провайдеру, пусть приедут мастера и настроят вам сеть.

Comment: Здесь не такой обьем чтобы мастера вызывать. Да и самому интересно.

Comment: но это не связано с тематикой сайта...